# Bitcoin cash with bicore and addressindex

Tags: development, bitcore

Bitcore runs a version of bitcoind where theres address index and we can search any addresses I have implemented the bitcoin insight block explorer and its working perfectly

I need to implement bitcoin cash (bitcoin ABC or Unlimited) but my question is can I search using addresses if I mix bitcore + bitcoin cash

I mean does bitcoin ABC comes with address index function ? thats compatible with bitcore ?

Comment: Add "txindex=1" to bitcoin.conf

Comment: @MCCCS I appreciate your answer but I am talking about address index. finding transactions that are made using an address. ie. I send the address on terminal or rpc and get list of tx associated with an address, NON WALLET ADDRESS

Answer (score -2):

Bitcoin Cash client does not support address index like Bitcoin, so you need a patched client to use this feature. You can use https://github.com/bitprim/bitcoin-abc. I also forked bitcoin-abc with address index feature. This repo is in https://github.com/Sotatek-DucPham/bitcoin-abc. Follow the build guild and get your bitcoind, remember to add `usecashaddr=0` in `bitcoin.conf` before run. Good luck.